# How to bring the cursor on the front while reading a line so that AtEndOfStream check works

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp

I have a file which contains 10 records. I am trying to read it using below. Now what is happening is I need to loopkup some company name from first row and need to create a file using that name (this is what I am doing in if loop).

In `Else` I need to do some data mining on all rows, including the first one already read. Now since `ReadLine` reads a line and then leaves the cursor at the end of the line (in below case the cursor will be after testing), so in the following reads the order will get messed up by 1, and either the first or the last row will be missed (based on where you re-read the line).

This is just for testing *(Please keep this. It's an example referred in the text)*

```
Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile("F:kushal\1094c.csv", 1)
Do While Not tsIn.AtEndOfStream 
    If firstRead Then
        l = tsIn.Skipline ' skip the header row
        l = tsIn.Readline
        dim tsOut : Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile("..\HCR Files\" & _
            ucase(formatFileDate(getSafeString(l))) & ".e", true, tristatefalse)
    Else
        l = tsIn.Readline
        l = left(l, (len(l) - 1))
        l = split(l, chr(34) & "," & chr(34))
        'All other stuff
    End if
Loop
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's an example referred in the text"? You don't refer to a line "This is just for testing" anywhere, and since VBScript doesn't support bare words the line would make your code sample invalid VBScript. Also, what "data mining" are you talking about? All your code snippet does is split the fields of the CSV rows.

Comment: @Kushal bhola were you able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim tsOut, firstRead

Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile("F:kushal\1094c.csv", 1)

If Not tsIn.AtEndOfStream Then tsIn.Skipline  'skip the header row

firstRead = True

Do While Not tsIn.AtEndOfStream 

    l = tsIn.Readline

    'save the first line
    If firstRead Then
        Set tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile("..\HCR Files\" & _
                   ucase(formatFileDate(getSafeString(l))) & _
                    ".e", true, tristatefalse)
        firstRead = False
    End If

    l = left(l, (len(l) - 1))
    l = split(l, chr(34) & "," & chr(34))
    'etc etc

Loop
```

Comment: This would likely do what the OP wants but could do with some explanation rather then just posting a code block.

Comment: @Lankymart - it's really just a re-arrangement of the OPs original code.  I assume they already know what each line does, so there did't seem to be a need for me to annotate them.

Comment: That's my point though Tim, when do we just write answers for the OP?

Comment: That's pretty much what I do.  I think we all have a different approach though.